# How do I call a function from a given class in a different class

Tags: c++, class

I want to declare a function in one class and run it in a different one.Below is the implementation of my class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <math.h>  
using namespace std;

int myNo = 1 + rand () % 10;
class Point { 
protected: int x; int y;
    Point() { 
        x = myNo; 
        y = myNo;
    }

    float distanceBetweenMeAndAnotherPoint (Point anotherPoint){ 
                 
        float xyz = sqrt(pow((x-x),2) + pow((y-y),2));   
        return xyz; 
    }
};

class Circle : public Point {
private:
    int radius;
    
    Circle(int x, int y){
        radius=myNo;
    } 

public:
    printCircleInfo(){ 
        cout << x << " " << y << " " << radius <<   " ";
        return 1;
    }Point Obj;
    bool doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle (Circle anotherCircle){
        if (radius +  radius >=Obj.distanceBetweenMeAndAnotherPoint)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

What should I replace Obj.distanceBetweenMeAndAnotherPoint with in order to call the function in this class?

> Please provide an example in your answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please take some effort to format your code as well as the question. It's quite unreadable in its current state.

Comment: Stop and think for a few moments on the likely result of `x - x`.

Comment: `printCircleInfo` needs a return type. `void` seems fitting.

Comment: This isn't a C++ question yet. If you don't know what math to use, you can't program. Figure out the math. A websearch for *calculate distance between two points* should get you started.

Comment: with the x-x It is supposed to be two different x values between 1 and 10 generated by the random number generator at the top. If there is a proper way to compare the two different x values then I would love to know it. Other wise thank you for the comment on the printCircle issue I never noticed it was missing a type.

Comment: I know the difference between 2 points is the sqrt of ((x2-x1)^2 +(y2-y1)^2)) that is what sqrt(pow((x-x),2) + pow((y-y),2)); is supposed to be doing if I have it typed out wrong then that's by bad. But none of this has any thing to do with my question of how to call the function from one class in a diffrent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the parameter that you get, like this:

```
float distanceBetweenMeAndAnotherPoint (Point anotherPoint){ 
    float dist = sqrt(pow((x-anotherPoint.x),2) + pow((y-anotherPoint.y),2));  
    return dist; 
}
```

Also for the bump method, use the parameter that you get. And additionally simplify boolean return value, no need for the if-else. Resulting with something like:

```
bool doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle (Circle anotherCircle) {
    return distanceBetweenMeAndAnotherPoint(anotherCircle)
        <= (radius +  anotherCircle.radius);
}
```

Note also that constructors should usually (though not necessarily) be `public`. In your case, the ctor of both classes, Point and Circle, should most likely be `public` and not `private` or `protected` to allow creation of objects of these types in your main.

Comment: Thank You your answer was very helpful though the things that are private and protected are supposed to be that way.